MAUI Blazor Hybrid different rendering on different platforms
I have a very simple component which, to my surprise, is rendered differently on different platforms despite being hosted inside a BlazorWebView.
On Windows, its rendered as expected. On Android, however, the text is not centered. How is this possible? I do not believe I have any platform-specific code.
And is it possible to resolve this issue, and get consistent output on both/all platforms?
The component:
<div Style="height:250px;background-color:coral;align-content: center;">
    <p style="text-align: center;">No items</p>
</div>

I have also re-created the component in MudBlazor here (same result): https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cumIbaGmMclCKdsj
Windows rendering:

Android rendering:


Yes, it is just the case. For this problem, you can create a new issue here.  Thanks for your support and feedback for Maui. :)

I have found the issue's link you created. As a summary, I will post an answer so that it will help others who have similar problems. Thanks for your support for Maui. :)

Yes, it is just the case as user1202032 said.
But we can use the following workaround:
<div Style="display:flex;height:250px;background-color:coral;">
    <p style="flex-grow: 1;text-align: center;align-self: center;">No items</p>
</div>

And we can check the following issue to get more information: MAUI Blazor Hybrid different rendering on different platforms.
